# AngularJS input type=datetime-local: expected ISO-8601-valid date string to be a date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

Using AngularJS and angular-resource 1.4.1, I have a super-simple `Event` service with a start date an optional end date:

```
angular.module('jtm.events').factory( 'Event', [
  '$resource',
  function($resource) {
    var Event = $resource( '/events/:id.json',
      {id: '@id'}
    );

    // EDIT: added this method
    Event.index = function() {
      var events = this.query();
      angular.forEach( events, function($event) {
        $event.start_date = new Date($event.start_date);
      });
      return events;
    };

    return Event;
  }
]);
```

A typical result of `Event.query()` looks like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    start_time: "2015-08-25T00:47:16Z",
    end_time: null
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

On the (end-user-facing) front-end I run these dates through a moment.js filter I set up, and that renders them as expected without any JS errors. However, on the admin Events form, I have:

```
<input type="datetime-local" ng-model="event.start_time" ng-required="true">
```

This is throwing:

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2015-08-25T00:47:16Z` to be a date
```

and rendering the placeholder `mm/dd/yyyy, --:-- --` mask in the admin form field.

Is this not a valid ISO 8601 date string? Do I need to change my service/module config somehow to get this to work?

## Edit

Instead of defining a custom `index` action, I overrode the `query` action configuration using an intercepter to wrap the `start_time` string in a proper `Date` object:

```
angular.module('jtm.events').factory( 'Event', [
  '$resource',
  function($resource) {
    var Event = $resource( '/events/:id.json',
      {id: '@id'},
      {
        query: {
          action: 'query',
          isArray: true,
          transformResponse: function(response) {
            response = angular.fromJson(response);
            angular.forEach( response, function($event) {
              $event.start_time = new Date($event.start_time);
            });
            return response;
          },
        },
      }
    );

    return Event;
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the date object in input element ng-model not the string.

```
use this 
start_time: new Date("2015-08-25T00:47:16Z")
ins ted of:-
start_time: "2015-08-25T00:47:16Z"
```

you can take help form this link

```
[plnkr]:http://plnkr.co/edit/QaA31F?p=preview
```

Comment: i would suggest to use some date time picker library since HTML input type="datetime-local" is only supported in chrome and in FF and IE it will become simple HTML input text element...

Comment: Thanks, that points me in the right direction. However, `start_time` is encapsulated within a service; how can I pass it into a date object from there instead of within the controller? (see edit)

Comment: thanks, @acobster, you can use a another modal variable bind to date field and can use ngModel options getter setter to track the changes and store the string representation of date in your object returned form service. you can use ng-change also to track changes.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using an interceptor on my `Event` service to accomplish the same.